# How to value a checkbox in the Gijgo grid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, grid

I'm trying to add a row to Gijgo grid with .addRow method containing a boolean type field rapresented by a checkbox into the grid, but I'm having some problems. After called AddRow the checkbox in the grid is always NOT checked. I tried with different ways passing "true/1/checked" but the result is the same, the checkbox is not selected.

where I'm mistaking?
Thank you very much

**View**

```
                grid = $("#grid").grid({
                    dataSource:  datasourceiniziale,
                    dataKey: "Id",
                    uiLibrary: "bootstrap",
                    columns:
                    [
                        { field: "Id", sortable: false, hidden: true },
                        { field: "description", title: "Elemento specifico", width: "70%"},
                        { field: "requtile", title: "Per capacità prof.le", align: 'center', type:"checkbox" },
                        { width: 34, type: "icon", icon: "glyphicon-remove", tooltip: "Elimina", events: { "click": Delete } }
                    ]
                });


                function Save() {
                    grid.addRow({ 
                        'Id': grid.count() + 1, 
                        'description': $("#elementospecifico").val(), 
                        'requtile' : 'true' //I tried with true/1/checked/on
                    });
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the cellDataBound in order to do that. You can find more info about this event at http://gijgo.com/Grid/Events/cellDataBound

```
grid = $("#grid").grid({
  dataSource:  datasourceiniziale,
  dataKey: "Id",
  uiLibrary: "bootstrap",
  columns:[
    { field: "Id", sortable: false, hidden: true },
    { field: "description", title: "Elemento specifico", width: "70%"},
    { field: "requtile", title: "Per capacità prof.le", align: 'center', type:"checkbox" },
    { width: 34, type: "icon", icon: "glyphicon-remove", tooltip: "Elimina", events: { "click": Delete } }
  ],
  cellDataBound, function (e, $wrapper, id, column, record) {
    if ('requtile' === column.field) {
      $wrapper.find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop( "checked", record.requtile);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Yeppa!...it works very well...Thank you very much Atanas